# How can this nested function interface be achieved?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to create a function A, which returns function B, where the valid inputs to function B depend on the inputs to function A.

The code below attempts to achieve this, but the linter expects the input for the second function to only ever be "a". I'd like valid inputs to be "a", "b", or "c" if "1" is passed into the first function.

```js
const dictionary = {
  "1": {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
  },
  "2": {
    a: "a",
    d: "d"
  }
}

const func = (componentKey: keyof typeof dictionary) => {
  const obj = dictionary[componentKey];

  return (nestedKey: keyof typeof obj) => {
    return dictionary[componentKey][nestedKey];
  };
};

// Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a"'. ts(2345)
const test = func("1")("b")
```

How can I set up a type structure such that `func("1")("b")` is valid but `func("1")("d")` is not?

Comment: Can you just use `dictionary["1"]["b"]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const func = <T, K extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K]>(dictionary: T, key1: K) => {
    return (key2: K2): T[K][K2] => {
        return dictionary[key1][key2]
    }
}

const test = func({
    "1": {
        a: "a",
        b: "b",
        c: "c"
    },
    "2": {
        a: "a",
        d: "d"
    }
} as const, "1")("b")

const test2 = func({
    "1": {
        a: "a",
        b: "b",
        c: "c"
    },
    "2": {
        a: "a",
        d: "d"
    }
} as const, "1")("d") // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAKgGhgaRgFMAPKIsAEwhgGsiBPEOGXAgJmLIursedYBtfAF0AfAApKAS2BRp4AIYAnBgC5WeegwCMG-AEo0YmAG8AUDCsxlRKAmVgYE7e33sDGrMJHD2I4zNLaxDbe0cYGTkFMBUGQW0dX1cRYKsAX3NM81BIWHJoNHgkYAkLEIAiHQqNcpDrRQ0KxQqcNPqAIyaO1vaQ4CbgCvb0tsr2GqD6hqaWsenIpsphkMz0mEUaXOg8KoqDCQqeg3Mc8EKCqE50RGQy9r3avpmYZt6FmC7XnvnpgdehiNfq8Jk8Po1XnNnlZKEsVtY1hstucoLtqgcKssjAB6bHEZTKEDKU5AA)